# React Native OAuth2 authentication with our own Authservice

Tags: android, react-native, oauth-2.0

We have an Authservice which following the OAuth2 protocoll. The url is the following:

```
https://auth.domaon.com/web/login?client_id=client&login_redirect_uri=%2Fweb%2Fauthorize&redirect_uri=????????&response_type=code&state=somestate
```

How can I use it to login my users in our mobile app?

I tryed to Linking it.

```
openAuth() {
    Linking.openURL('URL above');
}
componentDidMount() {
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this._handleURL);
}
_handleURL(event) {
    console.log(event.url);
    console.log(event.url.split('#')[1].split('=')[1].split('&')[0]);
}
```

I don't know what I have to add to my redirect URL to redirect to my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="schema"
    android:host="url" />
</intent-filter>
```

1. Have to add it to Manifest.xml
2. App accessible on the schema://url path.